# Using user input to retrieve data

Tags: python, string, input

I am trying to use a user's input to display specific information from a dictionary. Everything works fine besides the last print command. I enter 'pd' in hopes of it turning into print(pd['name']) like the line above it but I get an error.

Here is my code.

```
pd = {
    'name': 'project destroyer',
    'retail': '$200',
    'website': 'https://projectdestroyer.com/'
}

dashe = {
    'name': 'dashe',
    'retail': '$200',
    'website': 'https://dashe.com/'
}

favbot = input('What is your favorite bot? ')

print(pd['name'])
print(favbot['name'])
```

Here is my output and error message.

```
What is your favorite bot? pd
project destroyer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Phxn/Code/botfnder/bot_dict.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(favbot['name'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

**What is the difference in me manually entering pd['name'] as opposed to favbot = pd ... favbot['name']?**
I have thoroughly searched this error and just can't seem to understand how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `favbot` is a string inputted by the user so `favbot['name']` doesn't make sense.

Comment: You have to pass in integers instead of `'name'` in `favbot['name']`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so what would be a solution to get pd['name'] from a user entering 'pd'? Also thanks for the idea of listing dictionaries, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a list of dictionaries:

```
bots = [
{
   'name': 'project destroyer',
   'retail': '$200',
   'website': 'https://projectdestroyer.com/'
}, {
    'name': 'dashe',
    'retail': '$200',
    'website': 'https://dashe.com/'
}]
```

Then when you ask the use for a name, find it in the list

```
favbot = input('What is your favorite bot? ')
try:
    found = next(item for item in bots if item["name"] == favbot)
    print(found)
except:
    print("Not found")
```

Here's another way to do it with a loop, if you prefer that:

```
favbot = input('What is your favorite bot? ')
for bot in bots:
    if bot["name"] == favbot:
        print(bot)
        break
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway I could choose which individual value I want printed rather than the entire dictionary? Such as the retail price of Dashe, $200?

Comment: Sure, just change `print(found)` to `print(found["retail"])`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the quick and helpful responses.